# I am not able to identify the files kill spaces gradually once I start my laptop

Tags: partitioning

I am suffering from a problem when I run the command

```
akp@akp-PC:~$ sudo du -xhsc /* 2> /dev/null
```

It shows  7.2G  total, but surprisingly when I run the command

```
akp@akp-PC:~$ df -hl -x tmpf -x devtmpf
```

It shows that

```
               size  used  avail 
/dev/sda6       560G   15G  517G   3% /
```

I dont know what is using my space. Please help me